# Perl finding names of directories and files but determining they do not exist

Tags: perl, file-io

No matter what directory I use for TARGET, this Perl code correctly finds the name of every subdirectory and file in TARGET but then determines that none of them exist except for "." and "..".

```
my $source_dir = "C:\\path to directory\\TARGET;

opendir(my $DIR, $source_dir) || die $!;
while (my $file = readdir($DIR))
{
    my $file_exists = (-e $file ? "exists" : "does not exist");
    print("$file $file_exists\n");
}
```

Output:

```
. exists
.. exists
FILE does not exist # where FILE is the name of every other subdirectory or file in TARGET
```

What's truly baffling me is that if I change TARGET to one of it's subdirectories, the script successfully navigates to the subdirectory -- having previously determined that it does not exist -- and then produces the same output in the new subdirectory.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Please check your code. I am sure that if it does anything at all, you must have a terminal double quote in line 1, but you don't here, so I wonder if there are other typos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`readdir` only returns the filename, not the whole path.  Consequently, `-e $file` looks for `$file` in the current working directory, not in `$source_dir`.  Every directory contains entries named `.` and `..`, so those get found.  But none of the other files in the working directory have the same name as files in `$source_dir`, so they don't get found when `-e` goes looking for them.

So you need to combine `$source_dir` and `$file`:

```
use File::Spec::Functions qw/catfile/;

my $full_path = catfile($source_dir, $file);
my $file_exists = (-e $full_path ? "exists" : "does not exist");
print("$file $file_exists\n");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use some modules, what allows you many additional easying functions, my favorite is [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny). E.g.:

```
use 5.010;
use warnings;
use Path::Tiny;

$iter = path("C://Users/jm")->iterator;

while ( $path = $iter->() ) {
    say "$path";
}
```

The iterator automatically skips the `.` and the `..`, you can add option to recurse into subdirs and so on...